# Solve $x+y=84, \; \operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = \big( \gcd(x,y) \big)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I am interested in solving the system of equations

$$
(S) \; \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x + y = 84 \\
\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = \big( \gcd(x,y) \big)^2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$.

---

If $d = \gcd(x,y)$, then $d \mid 84$. Therefore:

$$ d \in \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 14, 21, 28, 42, 84 \rbrace. $$

Therefore, for each possible value $d$, we have to solve the system:

$$
(S) \; \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x + y = 84 \\
\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = d^2 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

However, I'm not sure how to solve such a system given $x+y$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$.

Comment: Maybe there is a way using the fact that $\operatorname{lcm}\left(a,b\right)=\frac{ab}{\gcd\left(a,b\right)}$

Comment: Maybe also use $lcm(x,y) = \frac{xy}{gcd(x,y)}$

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander pointed out in the comments, $\operatorname{lcm}(x, y) = d^2 \iff xy = \operatorname{lcm}(x, y) \operatorname{gcd}(x, y) = d^2d = d^3$, so $ y = \frac{d^3} x \implies x^2-84x+d^3=0 $ and it's easy to carry on from here.

Hope it helps.